# authblk package not supported \colorbox{} command

Tags: titles, authblk

I am using `authblk` package to display the authors. I will try to use background `yellow` color highlighted author names. But the `authblk` package is not supported.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[noblocks]{authblk}

\usepackage{color}
\newcommand{\snm}[1]{\fboxsep0pt\colorbox{yellow}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\title{Bad superscript with authblk / xltxtra}

\author{David \snm{Wilson}}
\affil{address1}

\author{Albert \snm{William}}    
\affil{address2}
  \maketitle

\snm{Sample Paragraph.} Sample Paragraph. Sample Paragraph. Sample Paragraph. Sample Paragraph. Sample Paragraph. Sample Paragraph. Sample Paragraph. Sample Paragraph. Sample Paragraph. 

\end{document}
```

The `\snm{}` command is working paragraph environment. The same command is not working inside the `\author{David \snm{Wilson}}` command. Please advice how to get the required color background in author names.

My Required Output:

[image]

The same output should be appeared author names. How to get this using `authblk` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will provide the required output with `authblk` package:

```
\newcommand{\snm}[1]{{\fboxsep.1pt%
\setbox1=\hbox{#1}%
\noexpand\colorbox{yellow}{\protect\phantom{#1}}%
\llap{#1\hbox{\protect\phantom{#1}}}\hskip-\wd1}}
```

Kindly note, this is intended to use inside the author block.  For the other text area, you may use the original definition with a different name.

Comment: Your solution is awesome. Your solution is working perfectly. I heartily  thank to you...